# How to implement C# code to java

Tags: java, c#

I follow the instruction form [here](https://github.com/ndrplz/opencv_skin_segmentation/blob/master/source) and the video from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRLa9h9iCQc). And i tried to implement it using JAVA. But i got an error when i tried to run it.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

the error from here

```
img_color_space.get(i, j)[i] = 0;
```

Here's the full code of C#

```
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
        GaussianBlur(frame, frame, Size(7,7), 1, 1);
        //medianBlur(frame, frame, 15);
        for(int r=0; r<frame.rows; ++r){
            for(int c=0; c<frame.cols; ++c) 
                // 0<H<0.25  -   0.15<S<0.9    -    0.2<V<0.95   
                if( (frame(r,c)[0]>5) && (frame(r,c)[0] < 17) && (frame(r,c)[1]>38) && (frame(r,c)[1]<250) && (frame(r,c)[2]>51) && (frame(r,c)[2]<242) ); // do nothing
                else for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) frame(r,c)[i] = 0;
        }

        /* BGR CONVERSION AND THRESHOLD */
        Mat1b frame_gray;
        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_HSV2BGR);
        cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(frame_gray, frame_gray, 60, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        morphologyEx(frame_gray, frame_gray, CV_MOP_ERODE, Mat1b(3,3,1), Point(-1, -1), 3);
        morphologyEx(frame_gray, frame_gray, CV_MOP_OPEN, Mat1b(7,7,1), Point(-1, -1), 1);
        morphologyEx(frame_gray, frame_gray, CV_MOP_CLOSE, Mat1b(9,9,1), Point(-1, -1), 1);

        medianBlur(frame_gray, frame_gray, 15);
    imshow("Threshold", frame_gray);

        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
        resize(frame, frame, Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
        imshow("Video",frame);
```

Here's the full code of JAVA :

```
        Mat img_color_space = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(src2, img_color_space, colorBgr2gray);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(img_color_space, img_color_space, new Size(7,7), 1,1);

        for (int i = 0; i < img_color_space.rows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img_color_space.cols(); j++) {
                if((img_color_space.get(i, j)[0] > 5) && (img_color_space.get(i, j)[0] < 17)
                    && (img_color_space.get(i, j)[1] > 38) && (img_color_space.get(i, j)[1] < 250)
                    && (img_color_space.get(i, j)[2] > 51) && (img_color_space.get(i, j)[2] < 242)){                    
                }else{
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        img_color_space.get(i, j)[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //bgr conversion and threshold
        Mat img_gray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img_color_space, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2BGR);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img_color_space, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.threshold(img_gray, img_gray, 60, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(img_gray, img_gray, Imgproc.MORPH_ERODE, new Mat(3,3,1), new Point(-1,-1),3);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(img_gray, img_gray, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, new Mat(7,7,1), new Point(-1,-1),1);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(img_gray, img_gray, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, new Mat(9,9,1), new Point(-1,-1),1);

        Imgproc.medianBlur(img_gray, img_gray, 15);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(path+"ouput.jpg",img_gray);
```

Is there something wrong in my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is there something wrong in my code?"  Yes, clearly. According to the error message, you used an array index that was out of bounds. What was the index used at the time? What were the valid bounds of that index?

Comment: You can debug to find which index the error talking about?

Comment: One of the problems is that you are using the post increment operator `i++` instead of the pre increment `++i` and that of course has a different behavior. Start with that

Comment: @3vts: Actually, when it's a stand-alone statement (such as the last statement of a 'for' loop), it makes absolutely no difference if you use pre or post increment.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that your original C# code has the last inner loop statement as:

```
frame(r,c)[i] = 0; //nested 'for' loop variables are r, c, & i
```

While your converted code has:

```
img_color_space.get(i, j)[i] = 0; //nested 'for' loop variables are i, j, & k
```

You are ignoring the inner 'for' loop 'k' variable

Change the statement to:

```
img_color_space.get(i, j)[k] = 0;
```